# Syncing two AWS Glue Data Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a use-case where I want to sync two AWS Glue Data Catalog residing on different accounts.

Does Glue emit notifications which can be published when a new database/table/partition is created/deleted? Or some other way of knowing what is happening in other Glue Data Catalog?

One way is to listen Cloudwatch notifications of that Glue account but according to Doc Cloudwatch notifications are not reliable:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/automating-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-events.html

Comment: Use AWS Glue API to sync other AWS account. Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: have you figured a way other than relying on cloud watch events?

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides an open source script(s) for that purpose. See [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/tree/master/utilities/Hive_metastore_migration#aws-glue-data-catalog-to-another-aws-glue-data-catalog-1)

Not sure how reliable and fast it is, but worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for this. But its more of migrating then syncing.

Comment: What if you run it periodically? or it must be synchronic for you?